# Cannot override form_widget and form_widget_compound

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I think that it is a bug. But maybe someone can help me to solve my problem.

I have overridden form theme in twig template by next code:

```
{% form_theme form 'path_to_my_fields_template.html.twig' %}
```

Also I have overridden some of the form fields:

```
{% form_theme form.some_field 'path_to_another_fields_template.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form.some_another_field 'path_to_another_fields_template.html.twig' %}
```

Then I overrode `form_widget_simple` in another file and included it in `path_to_another_fields_template.html.twig`, `path_to_my_fields_template.html.twig` using `use` twig-statement.

It works fine. But when I want to override `form_widget_compound` or `form_widget` it cannot be overridden and there are no errors, I see just `form_widget_compound` (applied to my form field) that declared in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

`path_to_my_fields_template.html.twig`:

```
{% use 'path_to_template_where_is_form_widget_simple.html.twig' %}
{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <tr>
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {% set span_class = ('field ' ~ span_class|default(''))|trim %}
            <td><span class="{{ span_class }}">{{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'inner' }}) }}</span></td>
        </tr>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

In the most cases `form_widget` generate form view with `form_widget_simple` and I'm happy. But when I have some related entities in my forms (compound field) all is bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please upload a fork of symfony-standard that reproduces this bug and open a ticket on the Symfony Issue Tracker (github.com/symfony/symfony/issues)?